# iPhone won't sync with my iTunes account

Tags: iphone, itunes, mp3, pc

I bought an iPhone 4 online and I'm trying to get my mp3s onto it. I downloaded iTunes on my PC and got them on there, but now I can't get the phone to find the music. I click on Music and it just says that it's empty and you can download music from the store. I'm new to apple product and to smart phones all together (I know I'm late don't judge me.) Please help.

Also, my PC and iPhone have never been synced. I don't know if that's relevant, but I thought I should throw that in here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run iTunes on your computer
2. Drag and drop your mp3s to the open iTunes window - this will add the songs to your iTunes library
3. Connect the iPhone to your PC
4. Click on the iPhone button once it appears in iTunes
5. Go to the Music tab once you entered into your iPhone in iTunes
6. Check the "Sync music" and "Entire music library" options as described in the first section here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1351
7. Click on the "Sync" button - this will transfer all the songs from your iTunes library to your iPhone